# How combine multiple output objects into a single object with jq

Tags: json, key, transform, jq

I'm trying to parse the output of a terraform state file.

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "terraform_version": "0.9.3",
    "serial": 0,
    "lineage": "ae1f2572-8fa6-4977-be73-3deac7529eff",
    "modules": [
        {
            "path": [
                "root"
            ],
            "outputs": {
                "elb_dns_name": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "web-elb-1019323532.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
                }
            },
            "resources": {},
            "depends_on": []
        },
        {
            "path": [
                "root",
                "elb"
            ],
            "outputs": {
                "dns_name": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "web-elb-1019323532.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
                }
            },
            "depends_on": []
        },
        {
            "path": [
                "root",
                "sg"
            ],
            "outputs": {
                "security_group_id": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "sg-5a677425"
                }
            },
            "depends_on": []
        },
        {
            "path": [
                "root",
                "web"
            ],
            "outputs": {
                "web_instance_ids": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "i-03676fa6ba43fbb9f,i-09f51a313146856cd"
                },
                "web_public_ips": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "34.207.194.186,34.203.236.205"
                }
            },
            "depends_on": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to get back a single json object where the output names are the keys and the values are the output values. Like in this example...

```
{
  "elb_dns_name": "web-elb-1019323532.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com",
  "dns_name": "web-elb-1019323532.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com",
  "security_group_id": "sg-5a677425",
  "web_instance_ids": "i-03676fa6ba43fbb9f,i-09f51a313146856cd",
  "web_public_ips": "34.207.194.186,34.203.236.205"
}
```

I have only be able to get back single objects using this `.modules[] | .outputs | to_entries | map({(.key) : .value.value }) | add`

```
{
  "elb_dns_name": "web-elb-1019323532.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
}
{
  "dns_name": "web-elb-1019323532.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
}
{
  "security_group_id": "sg-5a677425"
}
{
  "web_instance_ids": "i-03676fa6ba43fbb9f,i-09f51a313146856cd",
  "web_public_ips": "34.207.194.186,34.203.236.205"
}
```

So for some reason I can't post, because stackoverflow says I have too much code and not enough details... so now I'm doing a diary entry in order to type enough that I can hit the submit button... any minute... any ammount of characters now...

Okay so when I'm not building Code Pipelines at work I really like to play dota2. Only I think I'm pretty crappy at it. I mean I got 1200 hours in the gam and I'm still like 1.5k MMR trash.

Comment: Not too much code, too much data. You're expecting readers to parse thru your whole problem dataset, when it should be possible to demonstrate your problem in 1/2, 1/3 , 1/4 of the data you have included. You should read about [mcve] please ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I think this case called for including the entire dataset. If you look at the query I was trying, and the solution I found, you will see I had to start over from the beginning. I could have trimmed off the resources key, which is the bulk of the text, but I didn't feel as if including the entire object was a bad thing, and I still dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map_values` produces a simpler (or at least shorter) filter, and might be more efficient:

```
.modules | map(.outputs | map_values(.value) ) | add
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a solution but it took way longer than it should have (hours). Basically if at any time you lose the `,` in your lists than you messed up somewhere.

This is what I used `.modules | map(.outputs | to_entries[] | {(.key): .value.value}) | add`

It works, but maybe a better way.